# Monitor observable without being a subscriber

Tags: rxjs

Observables, I am becoming a big fan and my stack is starting to show it.

I would like to build some monitoring tools to hook into *n number of observables and be able to identify the number of current subscriptions without being a subscriber myself.

Peaking inside some of the Rx visualisation libraries I have noticed they monkey patch many of the operators, seems overkill?

Answer (score 2):

You could create an operator that would do it I suppose (disclaimer: untested):

```
Rx.Observable.prototype.activeSubscriptions = (subscriptionObserver) => {

  var source = this, subscriberCount = 0;
  return Rx.Observable.create((observer) => {
    var sharedSource = source.publish();

    var d1 = sharedSource.subscribe(observer);
    var d2 = sharedSource.subscribe(
      null,
      (e) => subscriptionObserver.onError(e),
      () =>  subscriptionObserver.onCompleted()
    );
    var d3 = Disposable.create(() => subscriptionObserver.onNext(--subscriberCount));

    var d4 = sharedSource.connect();
    subscriptionObserver.onNext(++subscriberCount);
    return new NaryDisposable([d1, d2, d3, d4]),
  });

};
```

Then it could be used like so:

```
var subscriptionObserver = Rx.Observer.create((x) => console.log("Current #: " + x);

Rx.Observable.fromEvent($button, 'click')
  .map(e => /*Map a value*/)
  .flatMap(x => $.get(`search?q=${x.value}`))
  .activeSubscriptions(subscriptionObserver)
  .subscribe();
```

This is mostly a naive implementation of the approach I would take. It won't be terribly performant (for that you would need to take a more performance oriented approach as some of the other operators are using). One caveat to this approach is that if you use it upstream of a `multicast` flavor you will only ever see one subscriber, because of how the implementation for those operators is shares subscriptions.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether these side-effect operators from `doOnXXX` family are available for RxJS. Anyway, here's the idea how this can be achieved in RxJava for single observable:

```
    final Subject<Upd, Upd> monitorSubj = ReplaySubject.create();

    Observable.just("one", "two")
        // ....
        .doOnSubscribe(() -> monitorSubj.onNext(Upd.SUBSCRIBE))
        .doOnUnsubscribe(() -> monitorSubj.onNext(Upd.UNSUBSCRIBE))
        // ....
        .subscribe(System.out::println);

    monitorSubj.subscribe(new Subscriber<Upd>() {

        private int num = 0;


        @Override
        public void onNext(final Upd upd) {
            switch (upd) {
                case SUBSCRIBE:
                    num++;
                    break;
                case UNSUBSCRIBE:
                    num--;
                    break;
            }
            System.out.println("subscribers change : num = " + num);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {
            // ...
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            // ...
        }

    });
```

Also other `doOnXXX` operators may be useful for your task.

Of course, you can do the same without `monitorSubj`, just call sorresponding update handling code directly. But you should consider thread safety of that handling code since it likely be called by multiple threads.

```
private int num = 0;
private final synchronized void handleUpd(final Upd upd) {
    switch (upd) {
        case SUBSCRIBE:
            num++;
            break;
        case UNSUBSCRIBE:
            num--;
            break;
    }
    System.out.println("subscribers change : num = " + num);
}
public void run() {
    Observable.just("one", "two")
        // ....
        .doOnSubscribe(() -> handleUpd(Upd.SUBSCRIBE))
        .doOnUnsubscribe(() -> handleUpd(Upd.UNSUBSCRIBE))
        // ....
        .subscribe(System.out::println);
}
```